# How to click on an element on Android UI which doesn't have resource ID or any name in python script

Tags: android, python, selenium, automation, appium

[image: My app UI by UI automatorviewer]

[image]

Hi, I am writing a script in python and using Appium server as backend. I am writing script for android application UI.
In Screenshot of UI automatorviewer, you can see few elements in app UI i.e. Books, Food, Water, Travel etc. All are clickable element. I want to click on 2nd element that is 'Food' and all the details are at right side i.e. index, class and package. It doesn't have any resource id or any name. Can any one please tell me how to click the 'Food' element. All have the diff-diff index number.

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
driver.findElementByXPath("//*[@class='android.widget.RelativeLayout' and @index='1']").Click();
```

Comment: Please change it according to the Python.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
WebElement frameLayout = driver.findElement(By.className("android.widget.FrameLayout"));
List<WebElement> obj = frameLayout.findElements(By.className("android.widget.RelativeLayout"));

boolean blnflag = false;

int i = 0;

while (!blnflag) {
    if (obj.get(i).getText().equalsIgnoreCase("Food")) {
        obj.get(i).click();
        blnflag = true;
    }   
    i++;
}
```